# How can I set the window size of a plot window?

Tags: plot, octave

Is it possible to set the window size / position of a plot window (figure)?

```
plot(0:20, sin(0:20))
```

Or is there any other possibility to change the size of the *print()* command?

```
print('aa.png', '-dpng')
```

Because the *-Sxsize,ysize* parameter doesn't change anything. The size of the written picture (aa.png) has always the same size as the plot window.

I'm using Octave 3.0.

Comment: You should probably not export it as raster graphics. Better choices than `png`: `svg` `pdf` `eps` `pdflatex`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
figure(1, 'position',[startx,starty,width,height]);
plot(0:20,sin(0:20));
```

[startx,starty] are the coordinates for the lower left corner of your figure (window).

You can also use the resolution option of the print function

```
print('aa.png','-dpng','-r300');
```

I guess the first solution might be better...

Regards

Comment: The position argument works great! But the resolution parameter doesn't seem to work. I've also found nothing in the manual about this parameter.

Comment: This works good with Matlab, but I don't know if there is an option like this in Octave...

Comment: It's `-S300,300` according to Octave [documentation](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_163.html).

Answer (score 12):

You can use the code below if you want to maximize:

```
figure(1,"position",get(0,"screensize"))
```

Comment: This made the chart itself fill the screen, but the labels and plotted points are still tiny. The answer from Mike Godin below worked better for me, it scaled everything. print('filename.png', '-dpng', '-S1280,720');

Answer (score 7):

As of octave version 4.2.2, the following works, as pointed out by [Janusz Lenar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154970/janusz-lenar):

```
print('filename.png', '-dpng', '-S1280,720');
```

Which scales the figure to create a 1280x720 pixel image.

Comment: Only this seems to work with Octave 5.1 with qt backend