# How to plot and display a square in Octave?

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, octave

I cannot achieve to plot a square in Octave. 
I cannot force equally scaled axes, so I am getting a rectangle instead:

[image]

The following trials are not working:

```
x = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]';
y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0];
plot(x, y), axis equal, axis([-1,2, -1,2])
% figure('Position', [10,10,100,100]); %[startx,starty,width,height]
% plot(x, y)
```

Probably I would need to specify a fixed window size and equally
scaled axes. I would be satisfied, when the first such display window
would show a correct square. A luxury solution would make the window
(or its content)
not interactively resizable.

Remarks:

1. I have Octave 3.2.4 on Windows XP.
2. The suggestion in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/607751/805681)
   does not work.

Comment: Odd, on Ubuntu, I get a nice square (as expected...): http://postimage.org/image/20h41uw04/

Comment: @Bart: so, likely a Windows problem (again). Thanks!

Comment: `axis square` used to work on my octave (winXP), but stopped since the last time I tried. Something broke the last time I updated to a newer version...

Comment: I have the same problem in Octave 3.4.2. Luckily I still have version 3.0.3 in parallel, and it works there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with Gnuplot's `windows` output device. Compare it against the `wxt` device:

### Gnuplot 4.4.3, WinXP

```
# Gnuplot, wxWidgets terminal
set terminal wxt size 200,400
set size ratio -1        # set size square
plot x

# Gnuplot, Windows terminal
set terminal windows size 200,400
set size ratio -1        # set size square
plot x
```

[image: gnuplot_wxWidgets_terminal]
[image: gnuplot_Windows_terminal]

Note that for the "win terminal", size affects the figure size including window title bar and status bar, while for the "wx terminal" it only sets the inner drawing area

---

### Octave 3.4.2, WinXP

Unfortunately, when I tried this in [Octave](http://wiki.octave.org/wiki.pl?OctaveForWindows), it still was not what it should be for both terminal types. In fact, [the problem](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/gnuplot-terminal-size-amp-position-td3307187.html) is that resizing the figure using `set(gcf,'position',[..])` had no effect:

```
# Octave, backend=Gnuplot, terminal=wxt/windows
graphics_toolkit gnuplot     # backend gnuplot
setenv('GNUTERM','wx')       # wx/windows
figure, set(gcf,'position',[100 100 200 400])
plot(-10:10, -10:10, 'r'), legend('x')
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
axis equal                   # axis square
```

Therefore, I had to manually resize the figures using the mouse to the specified size `(200,400)` (yes, I actually pulled a [virtual ruler](http://www.spadixbd.com/freetools/jruler.htm) and measured the pixels!). Finally call `refresh` command to replot:

[image: octave_gnuplot_wx_resized]
[image: octave_gnuplot_windows_resized]

The good news is that once you correctly set the figure size, `axis equal` is working for both terminals types.

On the other hand, the new FLTK backend is behaving correctly without any hacks, so you might wanna switch to it:

```
# Octave, backend=FLTK
graphics_toolkit fltk        # backend fltk
figure, set(gcf,'position',[100 100 200 400])
plot(-10:10, -10:10, 'r'), legend('x')
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
axis equal
```

[image: octave_fltk]

---

### MATLAB

For reference, here is the MATLAB output:

```
%# MATLAB
figure, set(gcf,'position',[100 100 200 400])
plot(-10:10, -10:10, 'r'), legend('x')
axis equal
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
```

[image: matlab]

Comment: Thank you for your thorough investigation (+1). Do you know how I could install FLTK for Octave? I did not find anything useful, only old stuff from 2005. If it is difficult, I would leave it and resize windows manually.

Comment: @Jiri: Follow [this link](http://wiki.octave.org/wiki.pl?OctaveForWindows) I previously posted, go to section "1.2. Octave-3.4.2-mingw + octaveforge pkgs", download the two 7zip files, and follow the instructions on how to extract. This 3.4.x version includes the new FLTK engine, no external dependencies required.

Comment: Another route is using Cygwin (Linux-like environment for Windows). You can obtain Octave 3.4.2 from the Cygwin installer itself. Instructions are available on the same page. I suggest you try the previous one first..

Comment: Thanks again! I am wondering why the download requires 'ilivid download manager'. I am not so keen to install such software on my PC. Why cannot it be done using normal download of the zip file?

Comment: @Jiri: If you have the know-how, you can always compile Octave yourself from the source code, though I suspect it is a bit involved on Windows. If not, you can use one of the community-contributed builds like the one I suggested. For now it is the only one offered for Windows 3.4.x release, and is hosted on a public file sharing website. The official installer is only available for the 3.2.x branch. Also you should know that Octave is a portable application, so it is perfectly safe to use a simple ZIP file instead of an installer.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (Octave on Linux):

```
x = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]';
y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0];
plot(x, y)
axis([-1,2, -1,2])
axis equal % or axis square
```

However, this only works until you resize the figure window, so I admit it is a little fidgety. So to get what you want with Octave, I guess you will have to place your figure window and make all changes before calling `axis equal`. I had very little luck with calling `axis equal` multiple times.

I guess this is related to limitations in GnuPlot (but I have no hard data supporting that claim), so you could try out other plotting libraries to see whether the exhibit the same behavior.

**edit**: 
For completeness a plot of what my code produces (if I refrain from resizing the figure window)

[image]

If you don't get anything working, you can try to debug the Octave code you are calling. In MATLAB you can inspect the corresponding code by typing `edit axis`, but in Octave I guess you have to give the complete path to the `axis.m` file (which is mentioned in `help axis`).

Comment: This is unfortunately not working on Windows. It corresponds in fact to my approach. But thanks anyhow! Do you have some specific plotting libraries in mind?

Comment: On Ubuntu with Octave 3.2.4 it simply works, without having to resize the window...

Comment: Well, I don't have any experience with plotting libraries (or Octave for that matter), but maybe the ones mentioned on [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave#Plotting_tools) might help?

Comment: @Egon on octave also you can just `edit axis.m`. Since this file is read-only, it will actually edit a copy, unless you first type `edit editinplace true` or put that in your `.octaverc`