# Trouble with Octave plots - can't display nor print in proportion

Tags: matlab, plot, gnuplot, octave

I am running:

Mac OSX: 10.8.4 (Mountain Lion),
Octave: 3.6.4,
GNUplot: 4.6 patchlevel 3,
Aquaterm: 1.1.1

I have been writing some Octave code so I can include plots in problem sets for my students. It plots 2d functions with grid lines resembling graph paper so that students can easily interact with the plot (draw tangent and calculate gradient, read off values, sketch other plots on the same axes, etc...).

The goal is to have the plot print on the page with 1cm graph paper.

My progress is such that I have everything in place except one thing - I can't get the figures to print in the right size! I can't even get them to print in the correct proportion.

Ideally, I'd like to save a pdf from the Aquaterm window, as I think the plots look better that way. My plan was to import the pdf into LaTeX at a consistent width (say, 15cm), and then have the code scale the graphs accordingly. However, this has not been working at all.

There are two variable to input:

length of x axis (in cm)
length of y axis (in cm)

Assume that the paper width is 15cm, and that the x axis never exceeds this length.

I am in quite a muddle about which commands I should be using... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried: [Printing a MATLAB plot in exact dimensions on paper](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3600945/97160)? Also if I remember correctly, the Gnuplot backend had some issues: [How to plot and display a square in Octave?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7370867/97160), but i'm not sure if that is still the case

Comment: Also related: [How to set the plot in matlab to a specific size?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7561999/97160)